# Алгоритм преобразования произвольной строки в хэш

Tags: алгоритм, математика, хеширование, lua

Нужен простой алгоритм преобразования строки в хэш вида 0хFFFFFF.

Ввод любой строки (Lua), после преобразования на экран выводится цвет (пример: `'Hello' --> 0x123FF1`).
Требования к алгоритму:

- произвольная по размеру строка преобразуется в фиксированный по размеру хэш
- одна и та же строка всегда будет отображать определенный хэш
- <s>возможность обратного преобразования</s> *(благодаря комментариям - погарячился)*

Прошу привести пример алгоритма простым математическим языком.

Comment: `возможность обратного преобразования` - ха-ха три раза

Comment: по поводу «обратного преобразования» — наверно, стоит начать с [википедийной статьи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Хеширование)

Comment: с обратным преобразованием - это уже алгоритм сжатия, даже в пегом дудочнике так не могли, сжать до 6 символов любую строку.

Comment: все посмеялись, но никто автору не пояснил. Получение хеша - это односторонняя операция. То есть имея строку вы можете получить хеш, но имея хеш вы не можете получить строку. Причина самая банальная - хеш он не уникален для строки, одному и тому же хешу может сооветсвовать несколько строк. К тому же, для получения строки по хешу нет эффективного алгоритма, все алгоритмы так или иначе выглядят как перебор всех возможных строк.

Comment: А длина точно три байта?

Comment: @gbg, предполагаю, что для простоты можно получить и большую строку - потом "обрезать" ее до нужного размера. Потеря данных допустима. Но на выходе ожидается 3 байта:)

Comment: не знаю, как в Lua, но обычно в языках программирования и связанных с ними библиотеках уже есть встроенные средства для полсчета хеша для элементарных типов данных, как строка. Может, вы поглядите в ту сторону? Например, если в Lua есть уже возможность получить хеш в виде 4 байт, то вам надо будет просто взять первые 3 байта оттуда. Минус этого а том, что разработчики всегда могут изменить код хеширования и он может быть не совместим с хешированием, применяяемым ранее.

Comment: Пара простых хэш-функций -- http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html

Comment: Выбирайте  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions